# Chocolate and a toy!

Tags: riddle

> I'm in the garden,
>   I've been to space,
>   I've flown across the sky.
>
> I keep you well,
>   I sum things up,
>   I sit and watch time fly.

What am I?

HINT:

> Botanical, Astronautical, Aeronautical, Medical, Literary, Temporal

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you:

> A capsule

I'm in the garden,

> "In botany a capsule is a type of simple, dry fruit produced by many species of flowering plants." - [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsule_(botany))

I've been to space,

> Part of rocket ship.

I've flown across the sky.

> Maybe this [escape capsule for a plane](http://interestingengineering.com/airplane-safety-system-proposes-escape-capsule-for-civil-aircraft/)?

I keep you well,

> Some medication is delivered by capsule.

I Sum things up,

> "An extremely brief condensation" [according to dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capsule)

I sit and watch time fly.

> Time capsule.

The title:

> Kinder surprise has a capsule inside a chocolate egg containing a toy.

Comment: Bingo, Yahtzee, House, Dominos, Checkmate.  The 2 clues you had trouble with were a little harder maybe but there were no red herrings.  Anyway, correct.

Comment: @BrentHackers Cheers. Nice puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

I think its

> Sunlight

Because:

I'm in the garden

> When it hits the earth

I've been to space,

> The sun is in space

I've flown across the sky.

> The way from the sun to earth

I keep you well

> Without light we would die (or what we eat)

I Sum things up,

> Not sure about that, but light combines dark places

I sit and watch time fly.

> Nothing is faster than light, so for a photon the time stands still

Comment: Well done.  Sunlight covers most of the points but there is a better fit.

Comment: What about the title?

Answer (score 3):

Are you:

> A clock

I'm in the garden,

> Sundial

I've been to space,

> GPS satellites have atomic clocks

I've flown across the sky.

> All planes have accurate clocks for navigation

I keep you well,

> Body clock

I Sum things up,

> Computers have an internal clock, which governs the processor cycles

I sit and watch time fly.

> Self evident!

The title:

> Chocolate and a toy is a Kinder Egg -- an egg timer is a kind of clock

Comment: Some of the reasoning is really good but this isn't the answer to the riddle.

Comment: @BrentHackers: Argh this is driving me crazy!!! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've been to space,

I've flown across the sky.

> Santa Claus

I'm in the garden

> He put children's gifts under the Christmas tree

I keep you well

> Another name of him is Father Christmas. Fathers keep their children well.

I Sum things up

> Santa Claus sums gifts up.

I sit and watch time fly

> Santa Claus sits and waits for Christmas.

Comment: Very seasonal.  Not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is

> Aquarius

I'm in the garden

> Another name of that is water bearer. (There is a gardener in garden)

I've been to space

> It is a Constellation. And it is in sky.

I've flown across the sky, I keep you well

> According to legends, it is the emperor of a wide portion of the sky and controls rain.

I Sum things up

> Gardener sums the garden up.

I sit and watch time fly

> Everyone sits and watches time fly.

Comment: Really cool answer with good explanations.  Not a bad fit but not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

My try:

> An atom

I'm in the garden,

> Well, that's obvious. I always collect atoms from my garden.

I've been to space,

> All the atoms in my garden were once part of a star that exploded, so they have traveled through space

I've flown across the sky.

> same as above

I keep you well,

> If one of my atoms splits, I will have a big problem

I Sum things up,

> You should never trust atoms they "make up everything" (intended bad pun here)

I sit and watch time fly.

> If nobody splits an atom intentionally they will be here for a really long time.

Comment: Interesting answer and probably the best fit so fat but it's not the (usually macro) object that I'm looking for.  Love the pun as reasoning too.

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> An amino acid

I'm in the garden,

> Plants are in the garden, built of amino acids

I've been to space,

> Amino acids have been detected in interstellar space

I've flown across the sky.

> They have been found on meteors too

I keep you well,

> We need amino acids to stay healthy

I Sum things up,

> They are building blocks, summing up to build complex proteins

I sit and watch time fly.

> They have been present on the earth since the earliest times, and have watched billions of years of evolution

The title:

> Chocolate and a toy is a Kinder Egg - and eggs are made mostly of protein, built from amino acids.

Comment: This is not the answer but I love it.  The explanations are cool and educational.  I especially like the one for the title.  The answer is (at least usually) a macro object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess its

> Air

Because:

I'm in the garden

> Its everywhere

I've been to space,

> The air is in space too

I've flown across the sky.

> Its everywhere

I keep you well

> without air, we can't breath

I Sum things up,

> Not sure about this..

I sit and watch time fly.

> Its everywhere

Comment: There is none in space

Comment: Well done.  It's not air but it covers a few of the points.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be

> my astronaut girl/boyfriend

because:
I'm in the garden:

> (S)he is in the garden that very instant because it's sunny outside

I've been to space,

> (S)he's an astronaut, so (s)he has been to space

I've flown across the sky.

> Again (s)he is an astronaut, plus (s)he travelled a lot and has taken the airplane sometimes.

I keep you well

> Yes indeed!

I Sum things up,

> (S)he's doing a great mathematic puzzle on StackExchange.

I sit and watch time fly.

> Even if it's a great puzzle, it's only to pass the time.

Comment: Now THAT is lateral, which is cool...  but it is not the answer to this riddle.

Comment: I know, but I liked this answer so I posted it :). May be I should edit it to say it's a lateral thinking answer ? I'm new so I'm not sure.

Comment: I joined on Friday so I'm the wrong person to ask.  But I like it.  I've heard far worse answers that turned out to be correct. :/